# HavingListeners on top of other listeners - android

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout that conatins a number of ImageViews and Buttons etc.  Each have their own listener allowing the user to set up various things.

After the user presses the start Button, I would like some of these listeners to go inactive while the whole screen has an onClickListener() that will listen for clicks anywhere on the screen.

How can this be done?

Comment: nullify the unneeded listeners and set an onclickListener for the whole View.

Comment: Set a listener for the RelativeLayout then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your parent layout an add the new listener to it. something like:

```
 frameLayout = ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout)); 

 screenClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
 };
 frameLayout.setOnClickListener(screenClickListener);
```

stop listeners:
 either

```
myClickListener = null
```

or

```
myClickableButton.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: im not quite sure if adding a clickListener to the parent hosting your widgets will automatically block your childrens listeners. Despite that i think manually deactivating listeners is always the way to go here.

Comment: myClickableButton.setClickable(false); did the job perfectly